# Why is .push() method giving duplicates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js

```js
{
    category: 'Music',
    id: '625064c2e12f6dec240bdfcb',
    correctAnswer: "Don't Leave Me This Way",
    incorrectAnswers: [
      'Ice Ice Baby',
      'In-A-Gadda-Da-Vida',
      'Rebirth of Slick (Cool Like Dat)'
    ],
    question: 'What song did Thelma Houston have a hit with in 1976?',
    tags: [ 'songs', 'one_hit_wonders', 'music' ],
    type: 'Multiple Choice',
    difficulty: 'hard',
    regions: []
  }
// Here is the response from the API...
  
   const oldArray = quizData[number].incorrectAnswers;
  oldArray.push(quizData[number].correctAnswer);
  console.log(oldArray);
// Here i am pushing the correctAnswer into the incorrect Answer array but my console.log keeps repeating the correct answer data, Why is this happening? Am i pushing it wrong? 

  ['An arrow', 'A lightning bolt', 'A bottle of wine', 'A Discus', 'A Discus', 'A Discus', 'A Discus', 'A Discus']
//Here is my console.log array.
// 'A Discus' keeps getting repeated 4 times, Same length of the present array, So the array has 7 values instead of just 3, What is going on?
```

Comment: What is `number`? You don't specify, but `quizData` seems to be an Object, so `number` doesn't make sense. Or perhaps your snippet is not complete.

Comment: @mykaf Yeah sorry the snippet is incomplete, [number] is a state...  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0), It is a state that changes the index when you click for the next question

Answer (score 1):

use the spread operator to avoid duplications

```
console.log( [...new Set(oldArray)])
```

```js
const list =   ['Anemia', 'Heart Attack', 'Paralysis', 'Epilepsy', 'Epilepsy']

console.log( [...new Set(list)])
```

Comment: Thank you @Sachila Ranawaka but its still not working It doubles the added value now, See the new console.log array values ['Relax', 'It Takes Two', 'Hot Child in the City', "It's Raining Men", "It's Raining Men"]....'It's Raining men' is getting repeated twice

Comment: It still doubles the value, See what i mean ['Anemia', 'Heart Attack', 'Paralysis', 'Epilepsy', 'Epilepsy']

Comment: see the example. it should remove the duplicates

Comment: [ '1940', '1956', '1961', '1948' ]
[ '1940', '1956', '1961', '1948', '1948' ]...Here is what i keep getting in my terminal, I don't know what i am doing wrong at this point, Thank you @Sachila Ranawaka

Comment: Is `correctAnswer` array?? if so do this instead of push.  `const oldArray = [...quizData[number].incorrectAnswers, ...quizData[number].correctAnswer]`

Comment: and then `console.log( [...new Set(oldArray)])`

Comment: Actually it has worked...You're a genius @Sachila Ranaka...Thank you very much